# how to load file in php using namepace except include from other directory

Tags: php, namespaces

how to load file in php using namepace except include from other directory!
I make a file a.php in namespac dir and b.php in namespac/super/admin dir by giving namespace namespace/super/admin and I want to use this file in a.php without require or include function. Kindly guide me that what methodology should be applied for this situation
code:

```
namespac/super/admin/b.php

<?php
namespace \super\admin;
class b{
    public function show(){
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
?>

namespac/a.php



<?php
use \namespac\super\admin;
class a extends b{

}
?>
```

Comment: Check this. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.nested

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called PHP Autoloader.
This might help: 
http://php-autoloader.malkusch.de/en/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ttgy0pIRiVQ